# Is it possible to import TextMate themes to IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: editor, intellij-idea, textmate

Is it any way to automate import TextMate themes to IntelliJ IDEA, like converter between these two formats?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Please [check the converter](https://github.com/JetBrains/colorSchemeTool) created by JetBrains.

> This is a tool to convert color schemes from TextMate to IntelliJ
>   Platform based products such as IntelliJ IDEA, RubyMine and PyCharm.
>
> Since the way highlighting works in TextMate is not an exact match for
>   the capabilities of IntelliJ Platform, we try to perform an
>   intelligent mapping between the two. In particular, color definitions
>   not existing in TextMate are remapped from the default IntelliJ color
>   scheme based on the background color used in the TextMate theme, to
>   ensure that the resulting text is readable.
>
> The table of the mappings is not yet complete; additions and
>   corrections are very much welcome.
>
> Note that the tool requires Python version 2.7. The default version of
>   Python installed on MacOS X is 2.6; you'll need to use Python from
>   MacPorts if you'd like to run the tool on MacOS X.

Comment: Do you know how I can use it?

Comment: Usage: colorSchemeTool <TextMate scheme> <IDEA/PyCharm/RubyMine scheme>

Comment: Ah thanks! There is missing hashbang... so when I tried `./colorSchemeTool.py` I got some errors `python colorSchemeTool.py` works fine

Comment: Can someone give a walkthrough of how to use this? Nothing is working for me.

Comment: The file convertion ran (and worked, seemingly). But when I try to import settings in Intellij 13, it says the file isnt valid :(

Comment: this worked fine for me, it wasn't 100% but it gave me a nice base on a theme I've done a while back for Sublime... I really didn't want to do it from scratch again.