# Custom syntax highlighting in JetBrains IDE's

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm, syntax-highlighting

Is there any way to add custom language syntax highlighting to JetBrains IDE's?

In my case, i want to highlight MATLAB code in PyCharm. IDE is suggesting me 'Mathematica' plugin, which doesn't work correctly.

Comment: Mathematica is a different language than MATLAB. Also, MATLAB is commercial...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can add any syntax highlighting by importing a corresponding TextMate bundle to PyCharm or any other JetBrains IDE.

Here's a [blog post covering this topic](http://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2013/06/textmate-bundles-in-pycharm/).

Comment: Thanks, @Topka, got it! What about themes? Tried to add `tomorrow night` from https://github.com/textmate/TextMate-Tomorrow-Theme via `add bundle`, but it is not visible in listboxes below. Can you suggest something?

Comment: matlab.bundle is broken in some ways, btw. Not all the commented lines are marked with gray. Some of them are interpreted in colors of code :(.

Comment: @s0upa1t, there's a separate thread covering themes support: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8506413/is-it-possible-to-import-textmate-themes-to-intellij-idea

Comment: Already found it, but it works in opposite direction (tm -> intellij)

Comment: I'm talking about this thing: Intellij theme is installed, corresponding bundle from textmate's github too. But it'is can't be recognized or shown. http://tinypic.com/r/nc1qi1/8

Answer (score 18):

For simple highlighting (without installing an IntelliJ plugin) you can simple create a [new file type](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/new-file-type.html):

- File | Settings | Editor | File Types - Add/Edit for Windows and Linux
- IntelliJ IDEA | Preferences | Editor | File Types - Add/Edit for macOS

and configure presentation and highlighting of keywords, comments, numbers etc. in files of a specific custom file type.