# Syntax highlighting for Pycharm - TextMate Plugin

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm

I am trying to follow the guide to installing additional plugins for *PyCharm Professional 2016.3* found here (PyCharm installed the plugin and it marks `.m` files as mathematica when I want matlab.):

- [Custom syntax highlighting in JetBrains IDE's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24840231/custom-syntax-highlighting-in-jetbrains-ides)

But without success. Viewing the installed plugins I currently have the *TextMate bundles support Version: 163.10154.50*. I have been trying to follow the instructions to installing the Textmate bundles in:

- [TextMate Bundles in PyCharm](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PYH/TextMate+Bundles+in+PyCharm#TextMateBundlesinPyCharm-Beforeyoustart)

but am unsure if this procedure is still valid. Similarly I have cloned the repository suggested in the link but can't navigate the *install plugin from disk* to the correct file/directory.

Comment: Install plugin from disk has no relation to the bundles repository. See the [related answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16451778/104891).

Comment: Thanks @CrazyCoder, related answer was very useful. Do you know of anything related to fix merging the syntax schemes with the editor themes, i.e. correct highlighting but using 'dark' themes, as it is now setting the background as white.

Comment: You just map the themes [here](http://i.imgur.com/91Pl0Oa.png).

Comment: @CrazyCoder, Worked perfectly. Thanks for the info.